# SQL- tsql -PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to make this table

```
CREATE TABLE x (clName CHAR(1), uName CHAR(2))
INSERT INTO x VALUES
 ('A','U1')
,('B','U1')
,('C','U4')
,('A','U2')
,('B','U2')
,('C','U5')
```

to this

A    B    C
U1   U1    U4
U2   U2    U5

I used Pivot

```
SELECT * FROM (

  SELECT [A],[B],[C] 
    FROM (SELECT clName, uName FROM X) a 
   PIVOT (MAX(uName) 
     FOR clName IN ([A],[B],[C])           
  ) p 

) AS b
```

But the result is:

A    B    C
U2    U2    U5

Any Idea?

Comment: The outer select completely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do build on @shree.pat18's answer.

You need a field that isn't being pivoted to help generate the rows. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE x (id INT,clName CHAR(1), uName CHAR(2))
INSERT INTO x VALUES
 (1,'A','U1')
,(1,'B','U1')
,(1,'C','U4')
,(2,'A','U2')
,(2,'B','U2')
,(2,'C','U5')

SELECT [A],[B],[C] 
  FROM (SELECT id,clName, uName FROM X) a 
 PIVOT (MAX(uName) FOR clName IN ([A],[B],[C])) p
```

Returns

```
A    B    C
---- ---- ----
U1   U1   U4
U2   U2   U5
```

Answer (score 3):

When you do `max(uName)`, there is lexicographical sorting and the maximum value is returned. Since you don't have a third dimension in your table to add in the pivot, you simply get the maximum value for each value in A,B and C, and the resultant pivot has 1 row and 3 columns.